# Simple JVM to JVMs communication framework?

Tags: frameworks, jvm, rmi, communication

I know there are lots of options out there, and sorry to ask such a similar question again, but it's different enough to warrant it -- I think. I have one Java app, let's call it the "master", that will do some work, and then it needs to inform other Java apps in other JVMs about it. Today they are on the same machine, but this will not always be the case.

I'd prefer something that has an easy way to add/remove listeners (i.e., other JVMs), etc...so RMI or Web Services are not suitable as there'd be too much manual coding there to look after who is what, etc.

I'd also like the ability to add new Java apps (again, in other JVMs obviously) to the master's 'notify list', whatever it may be, without much effort -- preferably without needing to rebuild the master app.

What I'd really like is an easy messaging/communication framework, which requires some simple configuration.

I'm overwhelmed by the amount of frameworks and options out there...JMS, jgroups, the various MQ frameworks, RMI, Jini, etc, Web Services.

I'm looking for fast, simple, reliable, and easy! Any suggestions? I don't need complex or particularly advanced features.

Answer (score 0):

Your master will have to be a server which is always available and the clients will have to register/unregister.

Maybe you can have a look at http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch2-basics/sample-tcp-server.html

Mina is also integrated in the Apache Camel project. (warning: Camel is a very addictive framework. The risk exists you will try to use it for all your future background processing :)